# QuantLib Installation on macOS 10.12 Sierra

Tags: c++, boost, quantlib

I am trying to install QuantLib on macOS Sierra, but when I run the check at the end:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/include/boost BermudanSwaption.cpp \
    -o bermudanswaption -L/usr/local/lib/ -lQuantLib
```

I receive the following error.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed `boost` via Homebrew. When I run `brew install boost`, I receive `boost-1.63.0 already installed`. I originally followed the instructions [here](http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml) using the Homebrew option, but  received the same final error and a deprecation warning when compiling:

```
warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
```

I changed the commands to the following and the deprecation warning went away, but the final error remains.

```
./configure --with-boost-include=/usr/local/include/ \
            --with-boost-lib=/usr/local/lib/ --prefix=/usr/local/ \
            CXXFLAGS='-O2 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9' \
            LDFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.9'

make && sudo make install
```

Comment: It's very simple. You MUST and MUST compile the entire QuantLib source code before trying to link the symbols.

Comment: Which symbol(s) are not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best so far I found is to just run `brew install quantlib`.